# Using nginx as reverse proxy with haproxy as loadbalancer

Tags: nginx, haproxy, transparent-proxy

I am tring to use nginx and haproxy together. I am doing that because haproxy does not support gzip compression. My aim is that first using nginx for gzip compression than forward it to haproxy for loadbalance. I am Ok until that point. But while doing this, I want to create transparent proxy. Since nginx does not support tproxy, I used X-Forward-For header . Then in haproxy configuration I added `source 0.0.0.0 usesrc hdr_ip(X-Forwarded-For,-1)` line but i got 503 error code in my browser. Without that line they works fine but not the way I want.

Thank you for any help, I hope I could explain what I want:)

Comment: What are you proxying upstream?  Why not enable compression there?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand exactly what you mean by saying "proxying upstream". Briefly my aim is that if a gzip request come, unzip it than load balance it backend servers as non-gzip, finally send back to client as gzip.

Comment: if you mean way of a request by saying "upstream". It should be exactly like that client(gzip)->nginx(gzip)->haproxy(non-gzip)->webserver(non-gzip)->haproxy(non-gzip)->nginx(gzip)->client(gzip) means it's reverse proxy...

Comment: I mean, why don't you enable gzip compression on the web or app server instead of adding haproxy or nginx into the mix?

Comment: I solved problem by reorganizing iptables rules. Thank you for interested in mahnsc...